# Google maps fetch intermediate place automatically

Tags: cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, phonegap-plugins

I need to integrate Google maps into my application, where I can get intermediate destination between two specified areas on road. I'm integrating this application using phone-gap. Is Google maps API provide any way to get all the important intermediate destinations between two areas.

Comment: How are you defining "intermediate destination"? Do you mean a waypoint on a planned route, or something that happens to be between your start and end point, or somewhere of interest that a route passes near?

Comment: well, what is an "important" way point vs an unimportant one - I think the waypoints would all be important

Comment: Well, i want the place name between source and destination